# Elasticsearch throws 'ElasticsearchIllegalStateException' part way through tests

Tags: testing, elasticsearch, groovy, junit

I've got a large Groovy application with a lot of JUnit integration tests (256), most of which use 'com.github.tlrx.elasticsearch-test', version: '1.2.1' to run elasticsearch locally.

part way through running all of the test classes all the test that use elasticsearch start throwing a 'ElasticsearchIllegalStateException' with message 'Failed to obtain node lock, is the following location writable?: [./target/elasticsearch-test/data/cluster-test-kiml42s-MacBook-Pro.local]'.

If I run any of these classes alone, it works fine.

This is my initialising code run in all @Befores:

```
    esSetup = new EsSetup();
    CreateIndex createIndex = createIndex(index)

    for(int i = 0; i < types.size(); i++){
        createIndex.withMapping(types[i], fromClassPath(mappings[i]))
    }

    esSetup.execute(deleteAll(), createIndex)
    client = esSetup.client()
```

And this if my teardown code run in the @Afters:

```
    client.admin().indices().prepareDelete(index).get()
```

This problem doesn't seem to happen on our build server, so it's only annoying and inconvinient, not a serious problem, but any help would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to have been cause by leaving the test nodes active while jUnit ran through all the tests - eventually it stopped being able to create new nodes. The solution is to use esSetup.terminate() in the after to destroy the nodes at the end of each test.

Here's an example of it being used correctly: https://gist.github.com/tlrx/4117854